# How to find the forgotten password by WPF from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I've a window in my WPF Project which helps the user to show the forgotten password, if the two security questions are being answered correctly. Unfortunately, my code doesn't work properly, therefore i need your kindly help.

In my code, i tried to read first and second answers from the textboxes, if they are match with **S_Question1** and **S_Question2** into SQL Server table, then should show the **Psswrd**, which has the same fields into the record.

**I really appreciate your gently feedback!**

My XML Code:

```
 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="SecurtyQuestionMother" Width="385"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="SecurityQuestionSchool" Width="385" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="10">
            <Button Name="match" 
                    Content="match" 
                    Width="50"
                    Click="CheckPassword"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="PasswordApears"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
 private void CheckPassword(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //updated...
    { 

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = "select * from Ceo where S_Question1 =@one and S_Question2=@two;";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@one", securityQ_mother_textbox.Text).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@two", securityQ_school_texbox.Text).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if ((reader["S_Question1"]).ToString() == securityQ_mother_textbox.Text || reader["S_Question2"].ToString() == SecurityQuestionSchool.Text)
            {
                PasswordApears.Content = $"Password is: {reader["Psswrd"]}"; //PasswordApears <- is a label
            }
            else
            {
                PasswordApears.Content = "Didn't match";
            }
        }
        conn.Close(); }
```

And this is the SQL Server Table:
[image: the SQL Server Table (CEO)]

Comment: Can you do some debugging and verify where the problem is? Are the values in the reader correct? Is it even connecting to the database properly? (Could be a casing issue if you're typing in lower case?) (Also you're using or and not and for the check.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply, it connects but it shows only one error (Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning CS0108 'AddCustomer.Close' hides inherited member 'Window.Close()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. SoleTrader .......\SoleTrader\Dialogs\AddCustomer.xaml 293 Active
)

Comment: Not related to your problem, but FYI:  the way in which you're storing the password is highly insecure.

Comment: lets think, instead of the password, it is the one another Field.

Comment: Oh... The problem is your SELECT statement. You only select the Psswrd field. So reader[6] doesn't exist. Either use SELECT * for all fields or just SELECT S_Question, S_Question2 and then reader[0] and reader[1]. Not sure how I missed this the first time sorry! You should also have a WHERE check on the ID field as this is unique. If you have 2 users with the same security answers you can't be certain which one will be returned.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks a lot for your reply and time investment! i have tried your method and Stein's method. still not change. I've really not idea. In the code, neither if nor else statement runs and shows any reaction. Here i am gonna update the question. The connection is successful!

Comment: The SqlDbType should be varchar, not char. Also in your WHERE clause you say the security anwsers must match exactly, which is fine, but if they don't nothing will be returned so the code will not fall into the reader.Read() bit and therefore will never say "Didn't match"

Answer (score 2):

I *really* don't mean to come off as- well- mean, but there is just *so much* wrong with how you are doing this. Please, take the time to read this answer and study up. It will make you a better developer.

## Password Security

*(Security standards change as threats evolve, make sure you're up to date on the latest best practices)*

**NEVER STORE PLAIN TEXT PASSWORDS**.

No secure website or application on Earth actually stores a user's password for authentication use. Instead, they do something called "hashing". Hashing is a one-way process that transforms an input into a statistically unique output of gibberish. This gibberish is called a "hash". The same input always produces the same hash, but the hash can't be converted back into the original input.

The *hash* is the thing that is stored in a database, not the password.

You can tell if the user entered the right password, because you can hash what they entered and compare it to the hash of the valid password. But since hashing is a one-way process, a hacker can't get the hash and then use it to find out the user's password in the event of a security breach.

This is why no secure website or application will ever send/show you your password if you forget it. *They don't actually have it, just the hash*. The best they can do is allow you to set a new password to replace the old one.

*Note: This is just a summary and not at all a full explanation of the proper technique for storing sensitive information like passwords. It leaves out many details (such as "salting"). Anyone working with this type of data should study the current best practices thoroughly.*

## SQL Injection

**NEVER PUT USER-ENTERED TEXT DIRECTLY INTO AN SQL STATEMENT**

You are currently creating your SQL query by taking the text input form the user and sticking it directly into the query string. You *expect* that the user will enter a legitimate answer, but they *could* enter *anything* else- including other SQL commands.

For exmaple, if the user entered this into `securityQ_mother_textbox`:

```
' OR 1=1--
```

Then your SQL statement would become:

```
select Psswrd from Ceo where S_Question1 ='' OR 1=1--' and S_Question2='{two}';
```

Which would return every record. They could also easily add other statements, like `DELETE` and wipe your whole database. This type of malitous input is called "SQL injection", because the attacker is "injecting" their SQL code into your application.

The *right* way to do this is using parameters:

```
string sql = "select Psswrd from Ceo where S_Question1 = @one and S_Question2= @two;";

...

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@one", securityQ_mother_textbox.Text).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@two", securityQ_school_texbox.Text).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
```

The [`SqlParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) class, "sanitizes" the input before adding it to the string. That means it changes the input in such a way that it can't be interpreted as anything other than a variable.

*Always use variables; never put the input directy into the command*.

## IDisposable

[Using objects that implement IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)

`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` all implement the `IDisposable` interface. Per the documentation linked above, this means they should be decalred in a `using` block. This would also call `conn.Close` for you.

## The Actual Problem With Your Code

In your SQL statement, you only select the `Psswrd` column, this means that only that column will be returned by `reader`. Calls like `reader[6]` and `reader[7]` will fail because only one column is actually available.

Also, columns are usually accessed by name, not index (number). For example `reader["First_Name"]`.

Comment: Hey Stein, thanks a lot for your kindly reply and your time investment, really appreciate it. I have been doing coding since 11 months and now i have to write a WPF Project for my school, i try my best to develop my coding knowledge. Anyway, I've tried your method as well. but sadly still not change :(, i've no any idea, neither if nor else statement runs and shows any reaction. I've updated the question!

Comment: Keith you may want to update your answer with my latest comment around the where clause in the SQL. If it doesn't match the code won't fall into reader.Read() and therefore will not display the "didn't match" - also the WHERE clause makes the checks in code redundant.